# Numerical sequence - 11, 89, 17, ?, 47, 62, ?, 10, 0

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

My friend from Math Stack Exchange gave me this sequence. He said that it isn't strictly a mathematical sequence, and that I need to find a pattern and then fill the question marks. These are the only terms.

> 11, 89, 17, ?, 47, 62, ?, 10, 0

Comment: Are you able to identify the correct answer, if such is provided?

Comment: @BenBarden yes .

Comment: This is actually from the [Algebrica](http://news.generiq.net/Trilogica/algebrica.html) IQ test. You really need to quote where you are getting these from properly, otherwise **this is plagiarism**. It isn't right to post other people's sequences or puzzles here and score rep off them without proper attribution!

Comment: Worse than that, **this is cheating** on a test - it's not right or fair to get this community to pass it for you!

Answer (score 4):

The final set is

> 11, 89, 17, 65, 47, 62, 50, 10, 0

The rule is

> each number after the first two is the digits of the two preceding numbers cross-multiplied, then added together.  So, if you have AB, CD, then the next number is going to be (A*D)+(B*C).  There are no numbers after the 0 because once you hit 0, there's no way to ever get anything else.

Comment: Well done for working this out - I gave it a +1 earlier - but just note that this question has since been found to come from a paid-up IQ test so we should start to be a bit more wary about answering questions of this type without investigating their source first... (You weren't to know this time, don't worry - just something to look out for from now on!) :)